# Multiple errors when using Hibernate and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm having issues using Hibernate on my project and can't find the error.

Errors:
[Errors Screenshot from Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCw9x.png)

hibernate.cfg.xml
[Hibernate Configuration File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O58gt.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Post the text itself. That way people can use a search engine and find a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing tag of the 'mapping' tag.

You either use

```
<mapping resource="Patient.hbm.xml"/>
```

or

```
<mapping resource="Patient.hbm.xml">
</mapping>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Missed that one.